# Canceling SelectedIndexChanged in WinForm ListView

Tags: winforms, listview

The winform ListView doesn't seem to have an easy way to cancel the SelectedIndexChanged event. I don't see a SelectedIndexChanging event either.

The code is my attempt. However the hightlight is gone and I was wondering if I need to color the selection also or if there's a better way to cancel. _prevSelectedIndex is the index from the last selection. I want the highlight to go back to the previous selection.

```
 lvSearchResults.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(lvSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged);
lvSearchResults.SelectedIndices.Clear();
lvSearchResults.SelectedIndices.Add(_prevSelectedIndex);
lvSearchResults.Items[_prevSelectedIndex].Selected = true;
lvSearchResults.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(lvSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have multiselect turned off you shouldn't have to call

```
SelectedIndices.Clear() Selectedndices.Add(..)
```

as well as:

```
Items[_prevSelectedIndex].Selected = true;
```

The latter will accomplish the same result.

I believe you're also adding a continually growing list of event handlers.  To remove an event handler you have to store an instance of the delegate then remove that instance;`-= new EventHandler(...)` isn't going to remove the handler.

Comment: Listview doesn't have a selectedIndex property. When Multiselect is faqlse, the SelectedIndices collection should only have one. Still whether multiselect is off or on, the behaviour is thye same.

The way I have the handlers (removing & adding) works fine. Otherwise the hanlder will be in an ...

Comment: ... infinite loop because of the 'Selected = true' statement.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way is to have a boolean property which you set to say, `true` when you dont want the event to fire. In the SelectedIndexChange event, you test to see if you should allow the event to continue firing else you return. Check my code out. The code below behaves the same.

```
     //somewhere on top
     private bool dontFireEvent = false;        

    //somewhere else
    dontFireEvent = true;
    treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nod.... bla bla //event won't fire
    dontFireEvent = false;

    //within the event code
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dontFireEvent)
            ProcessLogin();
    }
```